# Bash Script Log Rotation

Tags: bash, rotation

Can you please help me fix my log rotation assignment?

My bash script needs to take a required integer parameter, and an optional string parameter. The integer is the number of previous logs to keep, while the string is the path to the directory the logs are kept in (defaults to log). In this program I should validate that the integer parameter is provided and is a number. If a second parameter is provided, make sure the path given is to a directory and that I have write access to it. Do not worry about individual log files having write permissions.

Here are several sample runs of the program. Lines starting with '>' are responses from the program.

Lines starting with '#' are not printed, but a description of what action the program takes.

```
./logrot     
> number of days of logs to keep is required to be a non-negative integer     
./logrot -3     
> number of days of logs to keep is required to be a non-negative integer
./logrot 5 Not_A_Writeable_Directory     
>  Not_A_Writeable_Directory must be a path to a log directory with write access for $USER
./logrot 1     
#moves log/*.0.log to log/*.1.log     
#creates new log/*.0.log     
#deletes all other .log files
./logrot 2 otherfolder
#moves otherfolder/*.1.log to otherfolder/*.2.log
#moves otherfolder/*.0.log to otherfolder/*.1.log
#creates new otherfolder/*.0.log
#deletes all other .log files
```

My bash script code:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [-z "$1"] || ["1" -lt "0"]; then
    echo "number of days of logs to keep is required to be a non-negative integer"
    exit
    else
    count="$1"
fi

if [-z "$2"]; then
    dir=~/log
    else
    dir=$2
fi

if [ ! -d "$dir"]: then
    #echo "$dir must be a path to a log directory with write access for $USER
    #exit
    mkdir ~/log
    chmod 777 ~/log
    touch ~/log/*.0.log
fi

for (( i=$count-1; i>=0; i--))
    do
    next=$(($i+1))
    if [ ! -f "$dir/*.$i.log"]; then
    echo "Directory $dir/*.$i.log does not exist"
    else
    mv $dir/*.$i.log $dir/*.$next.log
    echo "moves $dir/*.$i.log to $dir/*.$next.log"
    exit
fi

done

touch $dir/*.0.log
```

Comment: wondering this works for you `if [-z "$1"] `? 
it should be `if [ -z "$1"  ]`

Comment: also even in the first line you are not comparing the parameter passed , should be `[ "$1" -lt 0 ]`